# Capistrano deploy:setup works but not deploy:check

Tags: deployment, capistrano

Testing capistrano with a simple recipe.

```
$ cap deploy:setup
  * executing `deploy:setup'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' mkdir -p /u/apps/ [..]
    [..]
```

`deploy:setup` works as exprected.

**However**

```
$ cap deploy:check
  * executing `deploy:check'
  * executing "test -d /u/apps/[..]
    [..]
```

When running `deploy:check` I get the following error:

```
The following dependencies failed. Please check them and try again:
--> You do not have permissions to write to `/u/apps/
[..]
--> `/u/apps/app/shared is not writable [..]
```

It seems that capistrano is not using sudo while in `deploy:check` mode.

**I don't get it!**

While in `deploy:setup` the whole directory structure was created by capistrano without any issue?

Why capistrano doesn't use sudo as in `deploy:check`?

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this issue and it turned out capistrano was creating all of the folders under the `<user>` group except for the shared folder.  SSH onto your server and do a long listing `ls -l`.  If you see - root - root - for the shared folder, you'll just need to update the permissions on the folder:

```
sudo chown <user> shared
sudo chgrp <user> shared
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15144815/341929): the trick is to explicitly configure Capistrano not to use `sudo`.
You can turn that off in your `deploy.rb` file with:

```
set :use_sudo, false
```

---

If you need to use sudo, how about using the [**sudo** DSL Action Invocation](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-DSL-Action-Invocation-Sudo) in your commands:

```
run "#{sudo} apachectl restart"
```

Comment: In my case I need to use sudo.

Comment: If you need to use sudo, how about using: `run "#{sudo} apachectl restart"` – the [**sudo** DSL Action Invocation](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-DSL-Action-Invocation-Sudo)?

Comment: Where can I change this option (sudo) for the operations in deploy:check **not the ones assigned by me** (see my question) ?

Comment: Try something easier first: how about using `set :use_sudo, true` in your `deploy.rb`?

Comment: It's already there, that's how the deploy:setup created the folder structure.